# What does "within the cluster" mean in the context of ClusterIP service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I have a Kubernetes cluster with the followings:

- A deployment of some demo web server
- A ClusterIP service that exposes this deployment pods

Now, I have the cluster IP of the service:

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   5d3h
svc-clusterip   ClusterIP   10.98.148.55   <none>        80/TCP    16m
```

Now I can see that I can access this service from the host (!) - not within a Pod or anything:

```
$ curl 10.98.148.55
Hello world ! Version 1
```

The thing is that I'm not sure if this capability is part of the definition of the ClusterIP service - i.e. is it guaranteed to work this way no matter what network plugin I use, or is this plugin-dependant.

The [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) state that:

> ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType

It's not clear what is meant by "within the cluster" - does that mean within a container (pod) in the cluster? or even from the nodes themselves as in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does that mean within a container (pod) in the cluster? or even from the nodes themselves

You can access the ClusterIP from KubeNode and pods. This IP is a virtual IP, and It only works within the cluster. One way it works is ( apart from CNI), Using Linux kernel's `iptables`/`IPVS` feature it rewrites the packet with Pod IP address and Load balances among the pods. These rules are maintained by `KubeProxy`

Answer (score 2):

The [definition from the Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) says it's reachable from within the cluster:

> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`.

The question is, how do we understand "the cluster"?

Well, [the Kubernetes cluster is](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/what-is-a-kubernetes-cluster):

> A Kubernetes cluster is a set of node machines for running containerized applications.

So answering your question:

> It's not clear what is meant by "within the cluster" - does that mean within a container (pod) in the cluster? or even from the nodes themselves as in the example above?

Yes, it means nodes + pods that are running on these nodes, so your behaviour is normal and expected.

Another question:

> The thing is that I'm not sure if this capability is part of the definition of the ClusterIP service - i.e. is it guaranteed to work this way no matter what network plugin I use, or is this plugin-dependant.

Basically the CNI plugin is responsible for [network communication for the pods](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/blob/spec-v0.4.0/SPEC.md#overview-1):

> A CNI plugin is responsible for inserting a network interface into the container network namespace (e.g. one end of a veth pair) and making any necessary changes on the host (e.g. attaching the other end of the veth into a bridge). It should then assign the IP to the interface and setup the routes consistent with the IP Address Management section by invoking appropriate IPAM plugin.

I did a quick test with a fresh [kubadm cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) setup without CNI plugin. I created a sample [Nginx deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment) and then service for it. What I observed?

- the service is created properly and has an IP address assigned, however...

  ```
  user@example-ubuntu-kubeadm-template-clear-1:~$ kubectl get svc
  NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
  kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   10m
  my-service   ClusterIP   10.109.245.27   <none>        80/TCP    6m52s
  ```
- the pods from the deployment did not started because the node has [a taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/):

  ```
  1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }
  ```

  In the `kubectl describe node {node-name}` I can find:

  ```
  container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized
  ```

So yeah, services are independent from the CNI plugin, but without CNI plugin you can not start any pods so services are useless.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cluster setup. If you are using a GKE cluster and it is setup as VPC native, then you will be able to reach the clusterIP service from a host in the same VPC.